# R Webscraping dataset

Tags: r, url, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to build up a dataset from UN FAO website (http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/). 
In this page are included a set of links to Countries.
Clicking on any of this link leads to the page of the specific Country in which are included news on the Country itself.
The idea would be to include in the dataset:

```
Country name
Country url (e.g. <http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=AFG>)
News url (e.g. <http://www.fao.org/afghanistan/news/detail-events/en/c/1045264/>) 
News title (e.g. World Food Day 2017 Celebrations in Afghanistan)
News date (e.g. 17/11/2017)
```

Yet, I have done the following:

```
## Import web page
FAO_Countries <- read_html("http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/")

## Import the urls I am interested in with 'selectorgadget'
FAO_Countries_urls <- FAO_Countries %>% 
html_nodes(".linkcountry") %>% 
html_attr("href")

## Import the links I am interested in with 'selectorgadget'
FAO_Countries_links <- FAO_Countries %>%
html_nodes(".linkcountry") %>% 
html_text()

## I create a dataframe with two previous objects
FAO_Countries_data <- data.frame(FAO_Countries_links=FAO_Countries_links, 
FAO_Countries_urls = FAO_Countries_urls, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: You should a) list the packages you have loaded, and b) indicate what difficulties you are having.

Comment: 1. The packages are:
   rvest,
     stringr,
     tidyr,
     data.table,
     plyr, 
     xml2.

2. I can't get News and News date

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution...

You should change dynamically the shortname (i.e. USA,SWE etc) if you want to get entire news as for all countries. An example for AFG is stated as below.

```
    library(jsonlite)

    shortname <-"AFG"
    news_url <- paste0("http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/common/allnews/en/?iso3=",shortname,"&allnews=no&limit=2")
    news<- fromJSON(news_url)

    title <- news[3]

    date <- news[6]

    cbind(date,title)

      date_format                                                                                                      title
    1  17/10/2017                                                            World Food Day 2017 Celebrations in Afghanistan
    2  16/10/2017 On World Food Day, the future of migration and rural development is highlighted in the Asia-Pacific region
```

If you want to get the content of the news, you can add this code :

```
 content <- news[5]
```